# Issue with proxy configuration

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, internet-explorer-8

I have a Win 2008 R2 server with IE10 installed on it. In the IE (and on firefox too), when I use option "Use Automatic Configuration Script" (this is as per the company policy to access internet) I am able to browse the internet but none of my local sites (eg. the site hosted on the same server using IIS) are opening. Perviously I was using a proxy server with "bypass proxy server for local address" option checked but the company now decommisioned the proxy and started using a cloud hosted ".pac" script.

Mean time this issue is only within one domain. In another domain where I have my local workstation is conncted, same ".pac" based proxy and the local sites are working fine.

Can you please share some thougts so that I can be in a good position to talk to the networks guys?

Thank you
Arun

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the PAC file to see if there is something in there about that domain.   This is a useful tool for checking issues.  https://code.google.com/p/pacparser/

Answer (score 0):

My network team did some configuration changes (undisclosed :-)) and that was the reason I got the problem.

Now they provided me a direct proxy address to use and as usual never bothered to explain what went wrong from their side and how they fixed.

Comment: I request admin/moderators to close or remove this question and answers as this is not useful for the community.